# Unity3d Android APK file post-processing (DLL encryption)

Tags: android, encryption, unity-game-engine, apk

My game is developed by Unity3d, I need to encrypt the DLL in APK.I add the following steps in build pipeline:

1. unzip the APK file
2. encrypt the managed dlls and replace with modified libmono.so (same Unity version, same ABI)
3. zip & jarsigner & zipalign

`jarsigner -verbose -keystore debug.keystore -signedjar "%1"_unaligned.apk "%1".apk %alias%`
`zipalign -f 4 "%1"_unaligned.apk "%1"_release.apk`

The resulting APK can install, but dies immediately after startup, no useful logcat, any helps?

Comment: *"encrypt the managed dlls"* - this doesn't sound very useful to me. You'd have to decrypt those DLLs to use them. Perhaps you mean that the code that results in the DLLs is first obfuscated. Obfuscation has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: Yes, encryption does not help much, it cannot prevent from coredumping, maybe it's the only way to secure code except il2cpp, and obfuscation is difficult to use in Unity3d because of too many reflection and magic methods (Awake/Update), any good tools?